# How to use case statement to deal with multiple return values

Tags: bash, exit-status, case

Take a look at these attempts:

```
$ case `true` in 0) echo success ;; *) echo fail ;; esac
fail
$ if `true` ; then
> echo "success"
> else 
> echo "fail"
> fi
success
```

Now, why is the case statement failing? You might wonder why I don't just use the `if` statement and I shall explain. My command if complex and might return different return codes on which I want act on. I don't want to run the command multiple times and I can't do:

```
my_command
res = $?
case $? in
...
esac
```

This is because I use `set -e` in my script and therefore if `my_command` returns failure the script aborts.

But I have a workaround...

```
set +e
my_command
res=$?
set -e
case $? in 
...
esac
```

But this is ugly, so returning to my initial question... why can I just use the `case my_command in ... esac` version?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use

```
case $(somecommand) in ...
```

to test the exit status of `somecommand` because the command substitution expands to the output of the command, not its exit status.

Using `$(true)` doesn't work since `true` doesn't produce any output on standard output.

You could do

```bsh
{ somecommand; err="$?"; } || true

case $err in
    0) echo success ;;
    *) echo fail
esac
```

This will stop the script running under `errexit` (`-e`) from exiting.

From the `bash` manual (from the description of `set -e`):

> The shell does not exit if the command that fails is
> part of the command list immediately following a while
> or until keyword, part of the test following the if or
> elif reserved words, **part of any command executed in a
> && or || list except the command following the final &&
> or ||**, any command in a pipeline but the last, or if the
> command's return value is being inverted with !.

In this case, with only the possibilities to either succeed or to fail, it would be easier to just do

```bsh
if somecommand; then
    echo success
else
    echo fail
fi
```

Answer (score 6):

The syntax

```
`command`
```

means to substitute the standard output of the command into the original command line. The output is not the same thing as the exit status. The `true` command doesn't produce any output, so your command is equivalent to:

```
case "" in
0) echo success ;;
*) echo fail ;;
esac
```

You can solve your problem this way:

```
case `my_command; echo $?` in 
...
esac
```

BTW, in the `if` command you don't need the backticks, it should just be:

```
if true
then echo successs
else echo fail
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Even with `set -e` you can still do:

```
if my_command
then
    echo success
else
    res=$?
    case $res in
      …
    esac
fi
```

Edit: you could also do

```
res=0
my_command || res=$?
case $res in
    …
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer: **Don't use `set -e` in this case.**

If you really have to, you may need to do something really ugly like:

```
case "$(bash -c 'my_command; echo "$?"')" in
    0) echo success ;;
    1) echo fail ;;
    2) echo "unexpected failure" ;;
    17) echo "wtf is this" ;;
    *) echo "I never thought this would happen" ;;
esac
```

But the obvious approach would be:

```
set +e
my_command
res="$?"
set -e
case "$res" in
    ...
```

---

Also note that **spaces are not allowed** around the equals sign in variable assignment in any shell.

Answer (score 0):

I fully agree; disabling -e and re-enabling it is ugly, and should be avoided.

Couple of options

```
if my_command; then
  echo "my_command ran ok"
else
  rc=$?
  echo "my_command exited with error code $rc"
fi
```

Or if you want to go the case route (and this is a bit hacky, but it should show capability as opposed to be used).

```
# PLEASE DO NOT ACTUALLY DO THIS
case "$(my_command > /dev/null && echo 0 || echo $?)" in
  0) echo yeah ;;
  11) echo "bummer" ;;
  *) echo meh ;;
esac
```

A less ugly solution might be (if you want to use case)

```
my_command && rc=0 || rc=1
case "$rc" in
...
esac
```